# Web3.js view method call() errors out as Returned values aren't valid, did it run out of gas

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am trying to call a view method of my contract that internally calls another contract's view method.

Contract:

```
//In Contract A (imports Contract B)
function getContractData() public view returns(string memory data){
  ContractB instance = ContractB(<address where ContractB is available>));
  return instance.getData();
}

//In Contract B
function getData() public view returns(string memory data){
  return "Hello";
}
```

JS:

```js
//Calling function
instance = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(<ContractA ABI>, <ContractA Address>);
console.log(await instance.methods.getContractData().call());
```

My methods work as expected in the Remix browser but when running on a network on geth using Web3, I get the error Returned Values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

I found some solutions changing the version of web3, they have not worked for me, I tried adding the from account and gas even though it does not make sense for a view method, but nothing has worked.

Where does it seem like I'm making an error?

Comment: Just as an additional information, view methods that do not refer to an instance of another method works as expected. If  I am trying to refer an instance of another contract, does it mean it needs gas now?

Comment: My guess that `instance` is not declared properly. There is a `)` missing. and if `ContractA ABI` is already in JSON then you don't have to parse it.

Comment: That was an error I made here. The instance is indeed declared properly and I ensured that by calling a view method that simply returns a message from ContractA.

Comment: The code is working fine on my end, and the smart contracts too on remix.

What is your web3 version, mine is `"web3": "^1.2.1"`. And I am using solidity version `0.5.1`

Comment: Have you tried ethers.js? Does it work? https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/

Comment: @iAmADeveloper thanks for trying it out. It works for me perfectly in Remix too. Also I tried to run with the same configuration as you web3 and solc, but I don't seem to be getting the desired result.

Comment: what is the result you are getting, when you are running it with 1.2.1 version

Comment: Please, help other to solve the issue with additional information:
1. Provide error messages you receive.
2. Provide chain you're connecting to: VM/Rinkeby/Mainnet.

Comment: @iAmADeveloper, I get the same error that says Returned values aren't valid, did it run out of gas.

Comment: @Paul Rumkin 1. I get an error saying Returned values aren't valid did you run out of gas. 2. I'm connecting to an internal network through Geth.

Comment: What version of Geth do you use? Have you tried to run this on Rinkeby network?

Comment: Hi @VishakhaLall, It would be great if you can share the github repo with contracts and web3 implementation.

Comment: @iAmADeveloper, hey I'm sorry but I am on an organisation network and wouldn't be able to upload code to GitHub or share the contracts.

Comment: No problem, I understand @VishakhaLall. I will create the custom contracts with the above details, but if possible please share your dependencies from package.json file or complete file.

Comment: @Paul Rumkin, my Geth version is 1.6.1

Comment: @iAmADeveloper thanks for the prompt updates, my package.json has solc version 0.5.1 and web3 version is 1.2.1

Comment: @VishakhaLall I tried the contract you have posted from both remix and web3.js, and it is working fine on my end I used geth 1.6.1 and infura ropsten net.

Comment: @iAmADeveloper, thanks for your efforts. I don't understand why it's failing at my end.

Comment: @VishakhaLall are you using private geth node or ropsten geth node?

Comment: @iAmADeveloper, it's a private Geth node

Comment: @VishakhaLall Try to connect web3 with ropsten net using infura and check it is working or not, This way we can ensure that there is some problem with the private node setup.

Comment: Please provide the full source code including how you connect to the web3 provider

Comment: Hi @StillFantasy, unfortunately the source code is on my organization's network and I'm trying to replicate the issue. As for the web3 connection is concerned, it seems correct because other view methods(of same contract) and transactions are working for me. It's only when I try to call a view method of a contract instance initialised in another contract.